# cell containing workbook name

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a excel sheet there in column A somewhere one cell is containing workbook name (suppose my work book name is abc then "abc" is in a cell in column A probably in range"A8 OR A9" ). I want to find out that row & delete all row above that. I using below code

```
Option Explicit

Sub abc()
    If Cells(8, 1).Value = ActiveWorkbook.Name Then
        Range("A1:A7").Delete
    Else
        Range("A1:A8").Delete
    End If    
End Sub
```

Pls if anyone can help me to solve the issue

Comment: So what is the issue? The code should work (Assuming you meant `Range("A1:A8").Delete)` instead of `Range("A:A8").Delete)`.

Comment: Put `?ActiveWorkbook.Name` in the Immediate window and hit [enter]. The problem should be instantly apparent.

Comment: Does your cell contain something like ***Book1*** or ***Book1.xlsm*** ??

Comment: nop, cell contains exactly workbook name

Comment: here I want to ask if I can use find instead of giving exact cell no as i am doing in above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find workbook name and delete the rows above the cell containing that name as:

```
Sub abc()
    Dim SearchCol As Long, SearchRow As Long
    Dim StrName As String
    Dim FoundCell As Range

    'get the workbook name after removing the extension
    StrName = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1))

    'search for the workbook name
    Set FoundCell = Cells.Find(What:=StrName, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If FoundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "File name not found in Sheet"   '---> if workbook name not found in the sheet
    Else
        Rows(1 & ":" & FoundCell.Row - 1).EntireRow.Delete   '---> delete the rows if name found
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT**:
**________________________________________________________________________________**

```
Option Explicit
Sub SearchWrkbookName()
    Dim oSht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    lastRow = 22

    Dim strSearch As String
    strSearch = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, (InStrRev(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".", -1, vbTextCompare) - 1)) '---> to remove extension from worksheet name

    Dim aCell As Range

    Set oSht = Sheets(1)
    Set aCell = oSht.Range("1:" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
       Rows("1:10").Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Edited code is working version of your code written in comments.

Comment: Yesterday I try below code, but I am confused why the error "variable not set" is appearing. I tried much to find it out I look everything correct. Pls go through my code to search the error

Comment: Option Explicit

Sub SearchWrkbookName()
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
lastRow = 22
Dim strSearch As String
strSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Dim aCell As Range
Set oSht = Sheets(1)
Set aCell = oSht.Range("A1" & lastRow).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
Rows("1:10").Select
End If
End Sub

Comment: @Nafis - `strSearch = ActiveWorkbook.Name` will give you the workbook name with extension

Comment: @Nafis - `oSht.Range("A1" & lastRow)` will give you `oSht.Range("A122)` as your `lastRow = 22`, that means you finding `strSearch` only in `Cell A122`

Comment: @Nafis - To confirm, in the question you have mentioned that you want to delete the rows however in the above code you are selecting first 10 rows. What actually are you looking for?

Comment: @Nafis - I've edited your code and added to my answer as EDIT. Check and let me know if its okay.

Comment: Yes, I want to delete above rows but just for testing my code I put the code for selecting rows  :-)

Comment: what does InstrRev do & what means -1 in InstrRev code line. Pls could you explain me only that code line. As I was unknown for that so I missed that.

Comment: @Nafis - InStrRev function searches for a substring within a string and returns the position of the substring. The Function searches from right to left (i.e. from the end to the start of the string). In the code above, InStrRev will search for `.` in `ActiveWorkbook.Name`. `-1` represents that the search will start from the end of the string. `vbTextCompare` is to perform text comparison.

Comment: @Nafis - See the details for InStrRev [here](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-instrrev-function.html).

Comment: THANKS A LOT, DEAR YOU ARE AWESOME.

Comment: I will check the your edited code & confirm shortly.

Comment: @Nafis - Did you get the chance to check my edited answer? Moreover, if my answer solved your question kindly mark it accepted.